# How to create a custom cursor in C# UWP with CoreCursorType.Custom?

Tags: c#, uwp

As far as I know "Cursor" don't exits in UWP.

I can change cursor with this code:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Arrow, 0);
```

How do I create a custom cursor with CoreCursorType.Custom?

```
CoreCursorType.Custom
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326026/custom-cursor-in-metro-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own cursor *.res resource file and contains the custom cursor to your project by add it to your package.manifest file. After that, you can use **CoreCursorType.Custom** enumeration option, and specify the **Id** of the custom cursor to use the custom cursor. There also have a thread in which @Azat Tazayan has introduced the detailed steps to implement it and you can refer to it:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14001796-bcd5-4b9d-9d7e-13bc6ba59d2d/uwp-how-to-set-a-pointer-cursor-as-a-circle-instead-of-a-window-default-cursor?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corecursor?view=winrt-20348

> To use a custom cursor, use the CoreCursorType.Custom enumeration
> option, and specify the Id of the custom cursor. You can add a .res
> resource file that contains the custom cursor to your project and
> include it in your assembly with the /win32res compiler option. The Id
> is the Cursor Resource ID specified in the .res file.

Personally I have used this working manual
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14001796-bcd5-4b9d-9d7e-13bc6ba59d2d/uwp-how-to-set-a-pointer-cursor-as-a-circle-instead-of-a-window-default-cursor?forum=wpdevelop

We need just proper `.res` file

For that we should do following

1. Create any C++ project.  For example **Dll**,  Add new C++ Dll project name it for example as *ResourcesComponent*.
2. Add a resource file to the project. [right-mouse] the project name `"ResourcesComponent" => Add New Item => Visual C++ => Resource File (.rc)`
3. Name the resource file for example `Resources.rc`
4. Add a cursor resource.  Double click on `Resources.rc` the it will open in  Resource View tab then Right click  on `"Resources.rc" => Add Resource => Cursor => New (Here you can modify cursor appearance by pen)`
5. Go back to solution explorer and now you will see resource.h file where you can find its id

> #define IDC_CURSOR1                     101

6. Build dll in **Release** mode
7. In **Release** sub folder you can find `Resource.res` file

Now we have proper `.res` file,  We should add it to our UWP project **root folder**.

1. Copy `Resource.res` file  to UWP project root directory. (You can delete DLL project as it is no longer needed )
2. Unload UWP project in VS.
3. Rigth click on unloaded project and select edit `.csproj`
4. in first or second PropertyGroup (where is Appname, TargetPlatform, etc ) add

> ```
>   <PropertyGroup>
>     .....
>   <Win32Resource>Resource.res</Win32Resource>
>   </ PropertyGroup>
> ```

5. Reload project
6. Use following code for set cursor in your image PointerEnter event handler

   Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor =
   new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Custom, 101);

If you need to create a colorized *.cur file use any free tools like I did [here](https://www.cursor.cc/). And just replace the source *.cur with a new one.
And if you need a small *.cur file just remember that by default its size is 32 x 32 pixels and you have draw your small image like I did.

Enjoy!

[image]